# How to multiple pagination in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, pagination

I've searched google and i found a similar question here in stack but that question is also not answered. I also tried to open a [github](https://github.com/vineethkrishnan/CI3-Multiple-Pagination) project and i tried to get it working on my computer just so i could see how it was done. I've got  it to run successfully but the problem is that whenever i click the links it gives me an error.

> http://localhost/ci-multiple-pagination/index.php/welcome/index?customer_page=2&
>
> Not Found The requested URL
>   /ci-multiple-pagination/index.php/welcome/index was not found on this
>   server.

The links have been giving me a problem. They either disappear or only one appears.

Is it possible to paginate two data on a single page in codeigniter? if so can you point me to the correct direction? i haven't been able to find one in google.

if not, i have little background on javascript so if i have no other choice can you also point me to the correct direction here?

In the mean time, how can i justify separating table of content and reviews?

I'm making a story website project where users post their own stories. For my story profile, there's the table of content for chapters and reviews. Both needed to be paginated.

How do i separate both into two views?

Edit: Additional question, i'm not comfortable with ajax or jquery but with javascript maybe. Is there anyway to do this with javascript? Is it possible to just use different view files for the paginations and call them to the same view(different) via javascript?

Comment: Based on the error it looks like you might not have `$config['base_url']` set correctly (or at all). But it could also be your code. Please show your code. Also, please do not ask multiple questions.

Comment: I gave up on it. It wasnt my code. I think i wrote it in a confusing way. The error was from a github project regarding a plugin for codeigniter for multiple pagination. Since it wasn't mine to begin with i would just not bother fixing the error since i assume it also uses javascript since its like that i'd rather just split the 2 paginations into 2 views for now then study javascript later on.